# Value Verification in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please advise what is the correct way to verify if key `x` is stored in a dictionary `dict`. and if it is, set a value `check` to True and otherwise it will be set to False.

```
check = True

try :
   y = d.x
except KeyError as e
   check = False
```

Or is it the right way to do one the following?

1. `check = dict.contains(x)`
2. `check = dict.has_key(x)`
3. `check = x in dict`
4. `check = x.is_elem(dict)`

Comment: use `check = x in d`

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach seems to be `x in d`